# PDF not rendering accordingly in JSP for Jasper Report Web Application

Tags: jsp, jasper-reports

I just made a web application for Jasper iReport in JSP. The report show from iReport application have no problem at all. But some of the reports didnt show accordingly in JSP. Looks like the pdf from JSP is not rendering correctly.Any idea how to fix this?
Im using apache-tomcat-7.0.91 and jasperreports-5.1.2 library from [Here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/)

JSP code :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/pdf; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*" %>

        <%
            Connection con;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/report", "root", "H@zel2002");
            File rf= new File(application.getRealPath("ireport/A2.jasper"));

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String dateString = format.format( new Date()   );
            Date date = format.parse ( request.getParameter("trip") ); 
            HashMap parameters = new HashMap();
            parameters.put("startdate",date);

            byte[] bytes= JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(rf.getPath(),parameters,con);
            //response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
            ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close(); 
        %>
```

[image: PDF from JSP]

[image: Result from iReport]

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: I did..no error while compile. Some reports in pdf show all the values like in iReport but the format didnt follow exactly.

Comment: Maybe this is font issue because some text is showing well. You should use font extensions

Comment: Solved it by changing to jasperreports-5.6.0 library